# Foreman change autosign behavior

Tags: puppet, foreman, puppet-foreman

We have setup [`foreman`](http://www.theforeman.org) in our infrastructure and started adding the first hosts. Now, after the setup is done, we'd like to change the default autosign behaviour we set with

```
--puppet-autosign
```

when installing using foreman-installer to disabled (and maybe later in reverse).

Any idea where this setting is hidden in `foreman`?

Answer (score 0):

The `foreman-installer` can be tweaked later by either running it again with a changed parameter, or by running it with `-i`.

Default value can be restored by dropping the line from: `/etc/foreman/foreman-installer/foreman-installer-answers.yaml` and running the installer again.